# Different shadow effects in SVG

Tags: svg

I know about `fegaussianblur` and its effects, but that doesn't seem to help me with this.  I found the code below from [here](http://codepen.io/juanbrujo/pen/yGpAK), and that works great in CSS, but is this type of thing possible in SVG, without path or CSS at all?

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 80px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  color: #131313;
  background-color: #e7e5e4;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  
  /*Important Code Below*/
  text-shadow:
    1px -1px #767676,
    -1px 2px #737272,
    -2px 4px #767474,
    -3px 6px #787777,
    -4px 8px #7b7a7a,
    -5px 10px #7f7d7d,
    -6px 12px #828181,
    -7px 14px #868585,
    -8px 16px #8b8a89,
    -9px 18px #8f8e8d,
    -10px 20px #949392,
    -11px 22px #999897,
    -12px 24px #9e9c9c,
    -13px 26px #a3a1a1,
    -14px 28px #a8a6a6,
    -15px 30px #adabab,
    -16px 32px #b2b1b0,
    -17px 34px #b7b6b5,
    -18px 36px #bcbbba,
    -19px 38px #c1bfbf,
    -20px 40px #c6c4c4,
    -21px 42px #cbc9c8,
    -22px 44px #cfcdcd,
    -23px 46px #d4d2d1,
    -24px 48px #d8d6d5,
    -25px 50px #dbdad9,
    -26px 52px #dfdddc,
    -27px 54px #e2e0df,
    -28px 56px #e4e3e2;
}
```

```html
<h1>Shadow Effect</h1>
```

Comment: Doesn't text-shadow itself just work on SVG content? It certainly does in Firefox.

Comment: It does, but I am trying to not use CSS because with either SVG or non-SVG you will see the stair-like pattern of the many text shadow effects (zoom in on the code snippet above after you run it).  I am wanting to use SVG so that no matter how far you zoom it, it looks smooth, and using CSS like that ruins that effect of SVG.

Comment: Up to a point. Filters are a raster effect.

Comment: This is a demo I made on codepen for SVG text effects. http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/qOqxpG. Look for the extrusion control. It *is* possible to draw the shadows directly using paths and gradients but it takes very fancy projection math.

Comment: @MichaelMullany that page you made is amazing!  I'm going to go through it later and see exactly how it works so i can use it on my SVG.